# Problems with reading a fixed width file?

Tags: python, pandas, screen-scraping, text-width

I'm trying to run this simple script:

```
from ibgeparser.microdados import Microdados
from ibgeparser.enums import Anos, Estados, Modalidades

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ano = Anos.DEZ
    estados = [Estados.ACRE]
    modalidades = [Modalidades.DOMICILIOS]

    ibgeparser = Microdados()
    ibgeparser.obter_dados_ibge(ano, estados, modalidades)
```

it keeps me sending this error:

```
E 240105 02:22:56 log:24] Error downloading documentation data:

    An error occurred while trying to download the documentation data.

[E 240105 02:22:56 log:24] Error extracting data from desired file:

    An error occurred while trying to extract data from the desired file.

[E 240105 02:22:56 log:24] Error accessing documentation data:

    An error occurred while trying to access the documentation data.

[I 240105 02:22:56 log:21] Downloading information from the state of Acre:

    Downloading information from the state of Acre.

[E 240105 02:25:07 log:24] Error downloading documentation data:

    An error occurred while trying to download the documentation data.

[E 240105 02:25:07 log:24] Error extracting data from desired file:

    An error occurred while trying to extract data from the desired file.

[E 240105 02:25:07 log:24] Error processing documentation data:

    An error occurred while processing the documentation data.
```

here is the microdados.py:

```
import os
import requests
import tempfile
import pandas as pd
import ibgeparser.enums
from ibgeparser.log import _Log as Log
from ibgeparser.enums import Anos, Estados, Modalidades
import urllib.request, shutil
from zipfile import ZipFile
from urllib.request import urlopen

log = Log()
log.init()

URL_DOCUMENTACAO='ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Censos/{}/Resultados_Gerais_da_Amostra/Microdados/Documentacao.zip'
URL_MICRODADOS='ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Censos/{}/Resultados_Gerais_da_Amostra/Microdados/{}.zip'
ARQUIVO_LAYOUT='Layout_microdados_Amostra.xls'
DIRETORIO_SAIDA='microdados-ibge'

class Microdados:
    def __criar_pasta_temporariaoraria(self):
        try:
            return tempfile.mkdtemp()
        except OSError as e :
            log.exception('Falha ao criar pasta temporaria: {}'.format(e))

    def __remover_pasta_temporariaoraria(self, pasta_temporaria:str):
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(pasta_temporaria)
        except OSError as e:
            log.exception('Falha ao remover pasta temporaria: {}'.format(e))
        
    def __obter_diretorio_trabalho(self):
        try:
            pasta_trabalho = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), DIRETORIO_SAIDA)
            if not os.path.exists(pasta_trabalho):
                os.makedirs(pasta_trabalho)

            return pasta_trabalho
        except OSError as e:
            log.exception('Falha ao obter pasta de trabalho: {}'.format(e))
        except Exception as e:
            log.exception('Falha ao obter pasta de trabalho: {}'.format(e))

    def __download_arquivo(self, url:str, destino:str):
        try:
            with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(destino, 'wb') as out_file:
                shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)

            return destino
        except Exception as e:
                log.error('Error in downloading the documentation: {}'.format(e))

    def __extrair_arquivo(self, caminho_origem:str, nome_arquivo:str, caminho_destino:str):
        try:
            with ZipFile(caminho_origem, 'r') as zf:
                log.debug('Extraindo o arquivo {}'.format(caminho_origem))

                for membro in zf.namelist():
                    if os.path.basename(membro) == nome_arquivo:
                        arquivo = zf.open(membro)
                        caminho_arquivo = os.path.join(caminho_destino, nome_arquivo)

                        destino = open(caminho_arquivo, "wb")

                        with arquivo, destino:
                            shutil.copyfileobj(arquivo, destino)

            return caminho_arquivo
        except Exception as e:
            log.error('Error at extracting the dates of the wished file: {}'.format(e))

    def __validar_enums(self, ano:enumerate=Anos.DEZ, estados:list=[], modalidades:list=[]):
        if Estados.TODOS in estados:
            estados = list(Estados)[:-1]
        
        if Modalidades.TODOS in modalidades:
            modalidades = list(Modalidades)[:-1]

        return ano, estados, modalidades

    def __obter_dados_documentacao(self, pasta_temporaria:str, pasta_trabalho:str, modalidades:list, ano:str):
        # extraindo csv de documentação para as modalidades escolhidas
        url = URL_DOCUMENTACAO.format(ano)
        log.debug('Arquivo de documentacao obtido de: {}'.format(url))

        # download e extração do zip
        arquivo_documentacao = self.__download_arquivo(url, os.path.join(pasta_temporaria, url.split('/')[-1]))
        log.debug('Arquivo de documentacao salvo em: {}'.format(arquivo_documentacao))

        # extração do zip
        arquivo_layout = self.__extrair_arquivo(arquivo_documentacao, ARQUIVO_LAYOUT, pasta_temporaria)
        log.debug('Arquivo de documentacao extraído em: {}'.format(arquivo_layout))
        
        # baixando csv pelas abas de modalidade
        div_columns={}
        ibge_datasets={}

        for enum_modalidade in modalidades:
            try:
                valor_modalidade, descricao_modalidade = enum_modalidade.value

                arquivo_csv = os.path.join(pasta_trabalho, 'Documentacao_{}.csv'.format(descricao_modalidade))
                log.debug('Arquivo de documentacao convertido para csv gerado em: {}'.format(arquivo_csv))

                ibge_desc=pd.read_excel(open(arquivo_layout, 'rb'), sheet_name=valor_modalidade, header=1).dropna(how='all', axis='columns')
                ibge_desc.to_csv(arquivo_csv, encoding="utf-8-sig")

                col_specification = list(zip(ibge_desc['POSIÇÃO INICIAL']-1, ibge_desc['POSIÇÃO FINAL']))
                ibge_datasets[descricao_modalidade] = ibge_desc
                div_columns[descricao_modalidade] = col_specification

                log.info('Obtendo as informações da documentação sobre {}'.format(descricao_modalidade))
            except Exception as e:
                log.error('Error at acessing the datas of documentation: {}'.format(e))

        return ibge_datasets, div_columns

    def obter_dados_ibge(self, ano:enumerate, estados:list, modalidades:list, header:bool=True):
        """
        Retorna os dados do censo baseado no ano, nos estados e modalidades selecionadas. Os arquivos são salvos na pasta
        'microdados-ibge' dentro do projeto.
        \n\n
        Obs.: Se for utilizar a opção TODOS, utilize somente esta opção dentro do da lista.

        Parâmetros:
            ano (enumerate): enum do ano.
            estados (list): lista de enums com os estados.
            modalidades (list): lista de enums com as modalidades.
            header (bool): adicionar header no csv (opcional, True).
        """

        # valida os enums, caso todas as opções sejam selecionadas
        ano, estados, modalidades = self.__validar_enums(ano, estados, modalidades)

        # cria pasta temporaria no sistema
        pasta_temporaria = self.__criar_pasta_temporariaoraria()
        log.debug('Arquivos temporarios salvos em {}'.format(pasta_temporaria))
    
        # obtem a pasta de trabalho para salvar o output (csv)
        pasta_trabalho = self.__obter_diretorio_trabalho()
        log.debug('Arquivos de saída salvos em {}'.format(pasta_trabalho))
    
        # captura o ano selecionado
        valor_ano, descricao_ano = ano.value

        # dados de documentação
        ibge_datasets, div_columns = self.__obter_dados_documentacao(pasta_temporaria, pasta_trabalho, modalidades, descricao_ano)

        # extraindo csv de todos os estados selecionados pelo usuario no pacote        
        for enum_estado in estados:
            try:
                valor_estado, estado, sigla = enum_estado.value

                log.info('Baixando informações do estado de {}'.format(estado))
                
                url = URL_MICRODADOS.format(descricao_ano, sigla)
                log.debug('Arquivo referente ao estado de {} extraído de: {}'.format(estado, url))

                # download dos dados do estado
                arquivo_zip_estado = self.__download_arquivo(url, os.path.join(pasta_temporaria, url.split('/')[-1]))
                log.debug('Arquivo zip do estado salvo em: {}'.format(arquivo_zip_estado))
                
                for enum_modalidade in modalidades:
                    try:
                        valor_modalidade, descricao_modalidade = enum_modalidade.value

                        nome_arquivo_modalidade = 'Amostra_{}_{}.txt'.format(descricao_modalidade, str(valor_estado))
                        log.debug('Nome arquivo modalidade: {}'.format(nome_arquivo_modalidade))

                        # extração do zip de dados do estado
                        arquivo_estado = self.__extrair_arquivo(arquivo_zip_estado, nome_arquivo_modalidade, pasta_temporaria)
                        log.debug('Arquivo do estado extraído em: {}'.format(arquivo_estado))

                        # conversão para csv
                        data = pd.read_fwf(arquivo_estado, colspecs=div_columns[descricao_modalidade])
                        data.columns = ibge_datasets[descricao_modalidade]['VAR'].tolist()

                        # salvando o csv
                        arquivo_csv = os.path.join(pasta_trabalho, '{}_{}.csv'.format(nome_arquivo_modalidade[:-4], sigla))
                        data.to_csv(arquivo_csv, encoding="utf-8-sig", header=header)

                        log.info('Arquivo de {} de modalidade {} extraído'.format(sigla, descricao_modalidade))
                        log.debug('Arquivo de {} de modalidade {} extraído em: {}'.format(sigla, descricao_modalidade, arquivo_csv))
                    except Exception as e:
                        log.error('Erro ao processar os dados de documentação: {}'.format(e))
            except Exception as e:
                log.error('Erro ao baixar os dados do estado: {}'.format(e))

        # apaga a pasta criada no diretório temporario                               
        self.__remover_pasta_temporariaoraria(pasta_temporaria)

    def obter_especificacao_coluna(self, palavra_de_busca:str, modalidades:list):
        """
        Retorna a específicação da coluna das modalidades selecionadas.\n\n
        Obs.: Se for utilizar a opção TODOS, utilize somente esta opção dentro do da lista.

        Parâmetros:
            palavra_de_busca (str): palavra para busca.
            modalidades (list): lista de enums com as modalidades.
        """

        # valida os enums, caso todas as opções sejam selecionadas
        ano, estados, modalidades = self.__validar_enums(modalidades=modalidades)

        # obtem a pasta de trabalho onde foram salvos os arquivos
        pasta_trabalho = self.__obter_diretorio_trabalho()
        log.debug('Arquivos estão salvos em {}'.format(pasta_trabalho))

        for enum_modalidade in modalidades:
            valor_modalidade, descricao_modalidade = enum_modalidade.value            

            doc = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(pasta_trabalho, 'Documentacao_{}.csv'.format(descricao_modalidade)))
            aux = doc.loc[doc['NOME'].str.contains(palavra_de_busca,case=False),['VAR','NOME']]

            for index, row in aux.iterrows():
                try:              
                    log.info('Procure por {} na modalidade de {} para: \n\n{} \n\nCom descrição da coluna de \n{}'
                        .format(row['VAR'], descricao_modalidade, row['NOME'].split(':')[0]," ".join(row['NOME'].split(':')[1:])))
                except IndexError:
                    log.error('Procure por {} na modalidade de {} para: \n\n{}\n\nCom descrição da coluna de \nsem descriçao'
                        .format(row['VAR'], descricao_modalidade, row['NOME'].split(':')[0:]))
```

why it doesn't find the key 'domicilios'? perharps the problem is in the very beginning, it seems that is not downloading the file. perharps is not pointed right? that's how the url should look: https://ftp.ibge.gov.br/Censos/Censo_Demografico_2010/Resultados_Gerais_da_Amostra/Microdados/

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]

Comment: There are many problems in your question: 1) Your code is 223 lines long. 2) All comments are in Portuguese so we can't fully understand what the code does. 3) You catch all Exception so we don't have the full traceback. 4) The error message (English) cannot be found in your code. Follow the links of @MatBailie.

Answer (score 0):

The code above works fine with 0 changes and no KeyError or "Error downloading". There is a clean run here: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13yCwwKqojUgSPtPZUcLzBwbwQXvYXGSD?usp=sharing

I suspect that the "Error downloading" indicates a firewall or other network hiccup between your CPU and the ftp.ibge.gov.br. Please consider running your work in a Google Colab or other cloud computer to bypass the firewall (or whatever).

Comment: yes, it worked. what is your suggestion to fix this? tried to disable firewall, but it still gives me the same error. someone in the github repository changed the url's setted on the code, but when I tried with the ones that he posted it gives me 404...